# Issue with KsStudio not installing Ksmon.sys

Tags: wdk

In Windows 10 (64 bit) 1803 with WDK 1803 when running ksstudio as administrator, there is always an error message saying can't install ksmon.sys. It is in same directory as ksstudio. I've tried windows 7 with wdk 7.1, 8.0, and 8.1 as well and get the same error. Tried searching the wdk forums and osr forums but came uo short. I have to be missing something or is it just broken and no one uses it? Anyone have this issue before and have any insight as to how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Here's the error I get on starting KsStudio and pressing ok
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOS4Z.png)

Comment: Can you copy/paste the full error output that you see, as well as the command you used which generated the error?

Comment: Okay I've identified the real issue, the KSMON.sys driver is not digitally signed. Who would have thought that would be the case.